# Картинки в классе. Можно ли?

Tags: php, ооп

есть класс

```
class Article
  {
   var $id;
   var $title;
   var $content;

    function __construct($id, $title, $content)
        {
           $this->id = $id;
           $this->title = $title;
           $this->content = $content;
        }
  }
```

Можно ли в качестве поля указать картинку? я сам догадался только до

```
$articleImage = new Article('7', 'Первый экземпляр с картинкой', '<img src="img/9467.jpg" alt="">');
```

но может можно лучше? сильно не пинать, только учусь.

Comment: При чём тут ООП?

Comment: я думал что классы это ООП? разве нет?

Comment: Повторяю, я только учусь. Может что то не так понимаю

Comment: @Дмитрий, вы обычную строку передаете с HTML-разметкой, а не картинку.

Comment: А как картинку передать?

Comment: классы - это не ООП. ООП - это идеология программирования, включающая в себя классы.

Comment: @Дмитрий, если вы хотите, чтобы вся ваша статья состояла из одной лишь картинки, то вы все делаете правильно. Но мне кажется, что вы не до конца понимаете, что такое HTML и типы данных в PHP. Лучше закрепите сначала эти основы основ прежде, чем трогать такие относительно сложные вещи, как классы и ООП.

Comment: Вы можете загрузить картинку и передать её в класс. Всё зависит от задачи, которая перед вами стоит. Если вы хотите изменить само изображение - вам нужно его загрузить. Если вы с помощью класса хотите генерить html - всё правильно, только лучше указывать не тэг, а только его атрибуты.

Comment: @Дмитрий чтобы картинку передать, её вначале нужно загрузить. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: @Trymount а как быть с утверждением что кроме классов никто больше не реализует ооп? Походит на мужика который ходит с белой бородой и красной одежде, который появляется только 31 декабря и передвигается с помощью упряжке с оленями в которой компанию ему составляет несовершенно летняя девушка в синим пальто, называется его внучкой. Кто это если не дед мороз?

Comment: @OlmerDale ну тут скорее можно метафорировать как "Дед Мороз - это не Новый год. Новый год, это праздник, событие, включающее в себя Деда Мороза". По сути ООП, это и правда скорее идеология, суть построения кода, мышления даже, нежели только классы. Классы - инструмент реализации ООП.

Comment: @SLy_huh программирование это точная наука, поэтому "скорее"  звучит как "ну можно и так сказать, а можно и нет". По факту, кто ещё реализует полиморфизм и наследование и полиморфизм?

Comment: @OlmerDale это бессмысленная дискуссия, которая не поможет ответу на вопрос. Это достаточно трудно объяснить в двух словах.

Comment: @Trymount глупо это когда нечем аргументировать! А Вы сами сказали что классы это не ооп. Я привел конкретные аргументы, поэтому очень хотел бы послушать ответное мнение с аргументами. Если хотите я создам новую тему?

Comment: @OlmerDale  существуют и бесклассовые объектно-ориентированные языки, например, Self, Lua https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @OlmerDale Да, создавайте

Comment: @OlmerDale http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50362/

Comment: @Trymount бесклассовые потому что ооп, это объектно а не классово.

Comment: у кого ооп - это классы... советую почитать статью о парадигмах программирования в вики хотя бы для начала. А по существу вопроса, автор, замените "ООП" на "класс", а "картинки" на "путь до изображения". Так будет корректней и возможно на вопрос ответят быстрее.

Comment: @StalkAlex Совет про "путь до изображения" несколько некорректен

Answer (score 1):

Поля (свойства) класса - это, по сути, обычные переменные, только с нюансами в части области видимости.

Если вы вдруг знаете, как "присвоить переменной картинку", то со свойствами класса ваш метод будет работать так же. Это было лирическое отступление.

Теперь про "картинку". "Картинка", в данном контексте - это ооооооооооооочень широкое понятие, под которым можно понимать практически что угодно, например:

- Набор байт, представляющий изображение в формате bmp
- .... jpg

...и тут еще сотня растровых форматов...

- Может быть это векторное изображение SVG

...пошли векторные форматы...

- Или это всего лишь имя файла изображения на локальной ФС
- Относительный URL на сайт
- URL на другой сайт
- Или это вообще ASCII-графика

и т.д.

Если рассматривать с точки зрения PHP, то наиболее вероятны и распространены два варианта использования:

- Вывод готового изображения пользователю в браузер. Это 99.9% случаев работы с изображениями в PHP.
- Обработка изображения с точки зрения графической информации. Обрезка, преобразование формата, нормализация, поворот, наложение эффектов и... в общем фотошоп. Это 0.09%.
- ну и еще 0.01% на адову экзотику

Для первого, самого распространенного случая, "поле картинка" - это будет строковая переменная, содержащая ссылку на изображение, которая уже будет использоваться при генерации HTML.

Для второго случая, "поле картинка" должно предоставлять доступ к самой графической информации. Для этого в PHP предусмотрено [некоторое количество расширений](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.utilspec.image.php)